# Issue with I.E and Java Applet. No support for JAVA APPLET

Tags: java, internet-explorer, applet

I am facing an issue with Java and I.E. I am trying to execute a web application which calls an applet. However I.E displays the error shown below:

[image]

I have installed JAVA SDK from: 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html
The version of Java I am using is (Java SE Development Kit 7u79 > dk-7u79-windows-x64.exe).

I followed the trouble shooting link (https://java.com/en/download/help/ie_tips.xml) mentioned under the session: (Why doesn't Java work in Internet Explorer after I just installed Java?)

I have restarted my I.E, re-installed Java but nothing helped.

I am out of ideas now, anyone who solved this issue please let me know.

System details:
Windows 8.1
jdk1.7.0_79
jre7

Thanks!

Update:
I noticed one more thing:

Java(tm) Plug-In SSV Helper      -> Enabled

Java(tm) Plug-In 2 SSV Helper    -> Enabled

Is there any other plug-in required for this?

Comment: See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

Comment: @AndrewThompson, So there is no solution to run applet in browser?

Comment: *"So there is no solution to run applet in browser?"* You think I'd know better than Oracle? What does this applet do, that cannot be done using JavaScript?